# network profile shows wrong reputation

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

I'm active in several StackExchange sites. My overall network profile shows different rep for one site. According to the local site, ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6385/teylyn my rep is 2051, bu t in the network profile it shows as 2151. How does that compute?

Screenshot to clarify: Overall network profile

[image]

Site summary:

[image]

Comment: It is retrieved _daily_ it is not live.

Comment: Ah, fine, but how can the overall profile show 100 rep more than I actually have? I could understand if it showed **less** because that could be due to a timer job not having run yet. But how about **more** rep than I have???

Comment: I am seeing 2,051 on both your ELU and network profiles?

Comment: Are you talking about the _graph_? That does look wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, it's the graph. I've added a screenshot to my Q. So, the graph in the overall profile does not show the correct rep. Is that a bug?

Comment: I was corrected by another dev - we cache for 10 minutes. Lets wait for that long to see if the graph corrects (we did a manual recalculation on your rep, so it should be OK now).

Comment: As a general note - if you see different reputation values (or badge values etc.) on different pages the answer is almost always caching.

Comment: Okee-dokee, I waited more than the ten minutes, and I can check back tomorrow, but the fact is that the network profile continues to show 100 **more** points than the site profile. How can caching be the cause for more rep than I have? How can you explain that away?